# LWC - Upload canvas image(.jpg, .png) file to the server(person account)

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload

I'm trying to make a functionality where I would like to allow users to save the captured images to the server. The general idea is:

- **Capture**/Create an image on an HTML5 canvas using a button and When the image is completed, allow users to save the canvas as an image file to the **server/person account**.

This **code will only** let you to **take your selfie** and **retake the image** and capture it on the canvas. I want it to send every new image files when I press on the **"Take Selfie Photo"** button. I've been trying to use Anonymous Apex code to send image back using initial **LinkedEntityId** but not fully understand how it works.

This is my code and examples: https://studio.webcomponents.dev/preview/spOqm9nMonL1DtibANXA/src/app.js

.html

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper" >
      <video width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
      <canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
      <button class="button-0" onclick={clickPhoto}>Take Selfie Photo</button>
      <button class="button-1" onclick={retakePhoto}>Retake Selfie Photo</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  async connectedCallback() {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    const video = this.template.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = stream;
  }

  // capture image
  clickPhoto() {
    const video = this.template.querySelector('video');
    const canvas = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    // data url of the image
    console.log(image_data_url);
    const take = this.template.querySelector('.button-0');
    const retake = this.template.querySelector('.button-1');
    retake.style.display = "block";
    take.style.display = "none";
  }

  retakePhoto() {
    const canvas = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear html5 canvas
    const take = this.template.querySelector('.button-0');
    const retake = this.template.querySelector('.button-1');
    retake.style.display = "none";
    take.style.display = "block"; 
  }
}
```

Updates on apex code:

.anom.apex

```
// instance image in base64 
String base64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII';

ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);
cv.Title = 'image.png';
cv.PathOnClient = 'image.png';
cv.IsMajorVersion = false;
insert cv;
System.debug('ContentVersion');
System.debug(cv.Id);

ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.ContentDocumentId = [
      SELECT ContentDocumentId 
      FROM ContentVersion 
      WHERE Id =: cv.Id
].ContentDocumentId;
cdl.LinkedEntityId = ''; // instance ID
cdl.ShareType = 'V';
cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert cdl;
System.debug('ContentDocumentLink');
System.debug(cdl.Id);
```

.cls

```
public with sharing class CustomUploadFile {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String uploadFile(String fileName, String base64Data, Id recordId) {
        // Decoding the base64Data
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.Title = fileName;
        cv.PathOnClient = '/' + fileName;
        // cv.FirstPublishLocationId = recordId;
        cv.FirstPublishLocationId = '';
        cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
        cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
        Insert cv;
        return 'File upload successfully!';
    }
}
```

Comment: What Apex have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, have you seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/306635/2984) regarding the upload process?

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox! I just put a update on the apex code. In my apex code, I'm using random base64(image) to upload to the LinkedEntityId. But I don't want to use base64 if is possible to just upload the canvas image after pressing the "Take Selfie Photo" button.

Comment: You can't send binary data, as my linked answer states. The data payload is JSON-encoded, so you need to use the data URL's content (which is also base-64 encoded already) to upload the file.

Comment: I have put a new .cls considering your answer. how do you think?

Comment: The class looks fine, just don't forget to create the ContentDocumentLink if you want to like the field to the record.