# How to add images from LWC to Files?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I want to add selfie upload on my screen flow. I have crete one LWC component and getting image from lwc Component.
LWC Component Js:

```
            this.canvasElement.height = this.videoElement.videoHeight;
            this.canvasElement.width = this.videoElement.videoWidth;
            const context = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(this.videoElement, 0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);
            const imageData = this.canvasElement.toDataURL('image/png');
            const imageElement = this.template.querySelector('.imageElement');
            imageElement.setAttribute('src', imageData);
            imageElement.classList.add('slds-show');
            imageElement.classList.remove('slds-hide');
```

i want to add captured image in salesforce files. Can any one help me to solve my issue. I am new to LWC.

Comment: Check this SFSE Question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377525/lwc-upload-canvas-image-jpg-png-file-to-the-serverperson-account